# QGIS: I can barely see the labels in layer panel

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, display, font, panel

So, I finally bit the bullet and upgraded to QGIS 3.2.3 Bonn.  However, for layers that are not turned on the font is a super light grey in the layer panel and I can barely read it.  How can I change what this looks like so I won't need to get glasses in 6 months?

Answer (score 3):

This question about [changing the background color of the layer panel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292386/change-layers-panel-background-color-in-qgis) may help. They recommend the Load QSS - US Themes plugin. Try the  themes "dark" and "wombat." The other themes actually make it harder to read deactivated layer names.

You can also create your own UI theme using the examples that come with the Load QSS plugin as templates. The qss files for these examples are available on GitHub: https://github.com/All4Gis/Load-QSS/tree/master/examples

---

Or you can change some display settings in the Options dialog (Settings menu > Options > General). Unfortunately you can't change the font color, but the night mapping* UI theme may help, or enlarging the font.

[image]

*There's a bug in QGIS 3.0 where switching to night mapping mode might cause QGIS to crash. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18669

*There's a bug in QGIS 3.2 where you can't turn on night mapping mode. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19944

---

Here's a rather silly workaround. Put every layer in its own group with the same name as the layer. When a group is disabled, the group name is still displayed in black.

[image]

Comment: Nice.  I like the idea of tweaking the UI via QSS.  Not really in love with any of the defaults provided.  I am fine tweaking the code but I can't seem to figure out where the files are or where to put the tweaked file on my computer.  I can't seem to find them anywhere.  Ideas?

Comment: The night mapping QSS file is here: QGIS 3.2\apps\qgis\resources\themes\Night Mapping. I couldn't find the QSS files for the themes that come with the Load QSS plugin on my computer. That's why I included the github link. You can use the ones on github as a template to create your own theme. Then save the QSS file anywhere and load it through the plugin.

Comment: Well...so I think I am stuck with one of the templates until QGIS realizes the new look is dumb.  I can't find any background color that works better than the templates which I still don't really like.  Wish I knew more about coding so I could just add a line in to change the font color.  It doesn't look like there are any lines in the QSS that address the font color, just backgrounds.  Thanks for the help, and if anyone figures this out please let me know!

Comment: You could make a feature request. https://issues.qgis.org