# Default UI Theme is still set to Dark Mode (QGIS 3.8)

Tags: qgis-3

I've noticed that the default for version 3.8 appears to be dark mode. I've set it Night Mapping and back to Default and it's still dark mode (I restarted both times). Any suggestions for setting ui to a white back ground (Blend of Gray is not cutting it for me either)? [image]

Comment: Try the workarounds I suggested for this similar (but not identical) question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/297033/81764. Also, this might be a bug, so maybe make a bug report: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation it appears this is happening because my OS UI is set to dark mode. This is strange because QGIS 3.6 and lower is not effected by the computer UI theme. Seems to be a bug.