# QGIS: Layer in layer tree list not visible

Tags: qgis, layers, visibility, layertree

I have a new problem with QGIS 3.28.7 (OS Linux Mint 21.1):

I'm looking for a layer in the layer tree list in a QGIS project, and use for that purpose the search box (left side below) - the result I can't see, because the system seems to use white letters before white background. When I click on the layer in the layer list, the name of the layer is visible again. Is that a bug in QGIS 3.28.7? Or has it to do with my OS Linux Mint 21.1?

[image: bug screenshot, white layer name]

sorry, here you are:
[image]

Comment: could you ad a screenshot of how it looks, when you click on the layer? I'm  not sure if I fully understand the issue here.

Comment: You see a screenshot above

Comment: Yes, but this is the situation when you don't see anything. I think it could help to see what is being displayed, when you click the layer

Comment: strange indeed...I found some workarounds, but I don't know either, why this is caused..
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297023/qgis-i-can-barely-see-the-labels-in-layer-panel?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: thanks a lot. This plugin <Load QSS - UI Themes> works (at least some of these themes work). The theme "minimalist" works best. Other themes cause other problems (the project cannot be loaded completely).  But with "minimalist" all problems are solved!

Comment: Glad this helped. I still wonder, if anyone would know WHY this issue arises in the first place.