# Where to find QSS files of the default QGIS UI theme?

Tags: qgis, user-interface, default, theme

In QGIS 3.28.10-Firenze on my Windows, I am trying to find where the default QGIS UI theme with its files is located.

[image: default_theme]

I could find both *"Blend of Gray"* and *"Night Mapping"* under this path `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\resources\themes`, albeit the default UI theme.

This directory `C:\Users\taras\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\themes` is empty.

My goal is to find files of the default UI theme: `style.qss` and `variables.qss`.

I tried the ["Load QSS - UI themes"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LoadQSS/) plugin, which was mentioned in this thread [Change Layers Panel background color in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292386/change-layers-panel-background-color-in-qgis). It has a <kbd>Default</kbd> button (`Default_btn`), however, it does refer to a specific file, rather of setting styles to an empty `""` value.

```py
# Restores style
def ResetStyle(self):
    self.app.setStyleSheet("")
    setActivated("")
    return
```

QGIS also has a `defaultThemePath()` variable inside the `qgsapplication.cpp` file, see [QGIS repository on the GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d296f0e513265f52eebe02804fe913ecf25d9ba6/src/core/qgsapplication.cpp#L730). But it is mostly about images and SVG-files.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS: I can barely see the labels in layer panel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297023/qgis-i-can-barely-see-the-labels-in-layer-panel)

Comment: Did you see [`qgisappstylesheet.cpp`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d296f0e513265f52eebe02804fe913ecf25d9ba6/src/app/qgisappstylesheet.cpp)? Perhaps the default theme is read from there.